# Xcode UITableView Row not highlighted when selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a working table view on my iphone app, and am implementing a second view using navigationController.

But when I try to select a cell on the initial view, it does not respond i.e. no highlighting in blue, no selection.

Can anyone suggest what I might have missed, or what is responsible for actually selecting the cell when the user taps it?

OK thanks for your suggestions - still no luck.  here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

        [cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue]; 

        UIView *selectionView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        selectionView.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView;
    }

    // format text

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    //[DetailView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    //[cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue]; 


    DetailView *detailView = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
    [DetailView release];

}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the method

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 Tells the delegate that the specified row is now selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without looking at your code I would say you have to add this line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

```
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

And also you have to implement this delegate method which gets called when you tap on cell of `UITableView`..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


}
```

Answer (score 6):

May be you have done this line of code in `cellForRowatIndexPath`::

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

If yes, then replace it with either of these:

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

or

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```